# How can I prove that if $W \cup \{p\}\vdash q$ then $W \vdash p\to q$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I saw this yesterday but I can't prove it! Could you please help we with it? I tried some rules but it became so complicated!
thank you.

> If $p$ can be deduced from a set $W \cup \{q\}$, then $p \to q$ can be deduced from $W$.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE! Please post some of your own ideas how to deal with the problem and we will be glad to guide you

Comment: This answer depends on the axioms and deduction rules. Which are they?

Comment: Hmmm, I may be wrong but I see that q $\rightarrow p can be deduced, not the other way.

Comment: What if W didn't need q to deduce p, and what if q is false?  Then W deduces p and p $\rightarrow$ q is *not* true (as p is true and q is false).

Comment: ...but then again I may be wrong.

Comment: The statement in the title ($p$ and $q$ have been swapped in the question body, probably by mistake) is known as the [Deduction Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem). How to prove it depends **entirely** on which kind of formal system you're working in. Sometimes it is completely trivial because it is itself a rule of inference; sometimes it requires a more or less complex proof. So you can't get a useful answer unless you reveal which proof system you're working in.

Comment: You can prove it by first formally deriving that $\vdash$CpCqp and $\vdash$CCpCqrCCpqCpr exist in your system (you don't necessarily need to get to these theorems to prove the rest, but these two WILL exist in the system if you can prove that result).  Suppose you can construct a derivation of $\vdash$ q from (W U {p}).  Now all the steps in that derivation are either instances of formal theses (theorems or axioms), an assumption, or a deduction from two previous steps using detachment.  If a step **x** qualifies as a thesis, then you can deduce C **y** **x** using CpCqp.

Comment: If a step **x** qualifies as an assumption made that you want to discharge, then you can deduce C **x** **x** using 1. CpCqp and 2. CCpCqrCCpqCpr (a condensed detachment proof is DD2.1.1).  If a step comes as deduced by two previous steps using detachment (or condensed detachment even), then call **x** the C $\alpha$ $\gamma$ formula, and **y** the $\beta$ formula which unifies with $\alpha$.  We've already deduced 3. C **z**_1 C $\alpha$ $\gamma$ and 4. C **z**_2 $\beta$ by the above.  Now we distribute 3. (using CCpCqrCCpqCpr) yielding C C **z**_1 $\alpha$ C **z**_2 $\gamma$.

Comment: Now C z_1 $\alpha$ and C z_2 $\beta$, since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ unify by the previous hypothesis, and z_1 and z_2 consist of variables not found in anywhere else in the formulas.  Thus, we can detach C z_3 $\gamma$, which gives us the assumption we've discharged to imply the formula $\gamma$ which we had in the previous derivation.  Consequently, whatever "q" we deduced from assumption p, we can deduce Cpq given W still in effect.

Comment: For the OP - the notation in @DougSpoonwood's comments is less commonly used than that which you are using, but its meaning is: "$Cab$" means "$a\implies b$." So, e.g., "$CpCqp$" means "$p\implies (q\implies p)$." (By the way, Doug, if you're going to answer a question using significantly different and uncommon notation, you should explain what it means.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Your comment is only partially correct. Cab means (a $\rightarrow$ b) and CpCqp means (p $\rightarrow$ (q $\rightarrow$ p))... or Cab means (a) $\rightarrow$ (b) and CpCqp means (p) $\rightarrow$ ((q) $\rightarrow$ (p)) When we have a rule of uniform substitution, full parenthesization efficiently maintains clarity. I mean consider that we had 1. p $\rightarrow$ (q $\rightarrow$ p) and substitute a $\rightarrow$ b for p in 1. Then we would have a $\rightarrow$ b $\rightarrow$ (q $\rightarrow$  a $\rightarrow$ b). But that string has different interpretations in terms of parsing.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the deduction theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem. How easy or hard it is to prove depends on exactly what your proof system is.

Some examples:

- Sam Buss (http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/handbookI/ChapterI.pdf, page 6) gives a proof of the deduction theorem for a system $\mathcal{F}$, which is essentially three lines long.
- Here's a more complicated one: http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse371/chapter8.pdf, page 6. Note that this is a different system - better for some purposes, worse for proving the deduction theorem.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: Why?  It answers the question.  (...presuming it is correct.)